# How to quickly create duplicate recessed portion?

Tags: modeling, topology

How to quickly create duplicate recessed portion?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I guess there are at least 2 ways of doing it: either you do it "for real" with topology, or you simulate it in the material with *Bump* or *Normal* maps

## Topology:

- Create a cylinder with as many vertices as you want
- Select the face loop
- *Select* > *Checker Deselect* so that only one of two faces is selected
- Keep the faces selected and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> > *Extrude* > *Individual Faces*
- Scale down these extrusions except on the Z axis with <kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

## Material:

- Create a surface with a series of crenels
- *Bake* this surface so that you have a *Normal* image
- Use this *Normal* for you whole ring
  (on my screenshot it's very quick made, sorry)

[image]